# Sending commands from one xterm window to another with Python

Tags: python, xterm

So I have a Python app that starts different xterm windows and in one window after the operation is finished it asks the user "Do you want to use these settings? y/n".
How can I send y to that xterm window, so that the user doesn't needs to type anything.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on linux (kde) and you just want to control the xterms by sending commands between them, you could try using dcop:

- http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/start-and-control-konsole-dcop
- http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyKDE3/dcopext.html

Otherwise you would need to actually use an inter-process communication (IPC) method between the two scripts as opposed to controlling the terminals:

- http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html
- http://docs.python.org/library/ipc.html
- Some other IPC or RPC library
- Simply listen on a basic socket and wait for ANYTHING. And then from the other app open a socket and write SOMETHING to signal.

Or at a very very basic level, you could have one script wait on file output from the other. So once your first xterm finishes, it could write a file that the other script sees.

These are all varying difficulties of solutions.

Comment: You may consider include this link: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/start-and-control-konsole-dbus about controlling konsole through dbus (from the same author of dcop tutorial)